# Why is "fahr-32" in this C example instead of just simply "32"?

Tags: c

I was wondering why, in this example, the 32 value has fahr- in front of it. Is it necessary or just there to specify something?

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* print Fahrenheit-Celsius table
    for fahr = 0, 20, ..., 300 */
main()
{
    int fahr, celsius;
    int lower, upper, step;

    lower = 0;      /* lower limit of temperature scale */
    upper = 300;    /* upper limit */
    step = 20;      /* step size */

    fahr = lower;
    while (fahr <= upper) {
        celsius = 5 * (fahr-32) / 9;
        printf("%d\t%d\n", fahr, celsius);
        fahr = fahr + step;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Formula](http://www.manuelsweb.com/temp.htm)

Comment: `-` is for substraction. `fahr-32` is same as `fahr - 32`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this example you are converting from Fahrenheit to Celsius temperatures.

`fahr-32` in this example means take the value in the variable called `fahr` (which contains a Fahrenheit temperature) and subtract 32. So `fahr` is a variable name and `-` just means minus.

Comment: Oh OK that is where it confused me. I thought you were supposed to always put blanks around the operators. Thanks.

Comment: @user3099345 It's a good thing to do to make the code more readable, but is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

fahr represents the current temperature in farenheit units. It stars at lower and goes to upper.

This formula converts farenheit to celsius:

```
celsius = 5 * (fahr-32) / 9;
```

An extra variable is used , so the lower variable remains unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

'fahr' is an integer variable in this program, and in the course of the while() loop, the value of 'fahr' increases by the value in the 'step' variable with every execution loop.

For the first iteration (or 'run') of the loop, 'fahr' might as well not be there because its value is 0. After that though, the value of it increases, and thus becomes an important part of the calculation for 'celsius', i.e. calsius = 5 * (20-32) /9 in the second loop.

Comment: Why do you say it may as well not be there because its value is 0? Having a value of 0 is still a reason to be there.